# How to calculate the maximum volume of a conical frustum?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, optimization, volume

This is just a question for my research on the ideal cup size to minimize the amount of plastic used.

Assuming that the conical frustum is in a shape of a cup. How do I go about in solving the maximum volume of this cup using calculus to minimize the amount of plastic? I stumbled upon some sort of confusion between integration and optimization, can someone explain to me what would be the best method in approaching this? (And please involve calculus, thanks!)

Comment: The shape is somewhat under-specified.  Do you have a particular volume for which you want to minimize the surface area, which minimizes the amount of material required, or do you have a specific amount of material available for which you want to make a cup that will hold the greatest possible volume?  You will need to indicate either a desired height, or a slant height, or a base radius for the frustum.  The volume [found here for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891163/volume-of-a-frustum?rq=1 ] will suggest why more detail is needed.

Comment: You can solve using Lagrange Multiplier method. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024363/optimizing-a-conical-frustum-using-partial-differentiation, for example. If you do not have a lid on top, you will have to make that adjustment.

Comment: @boojum - Lets say if I wanted my cup to hold a maximum of 100ml of water, how do I minimize my surface area and what concepts would I have to apply in doing so?

Comment: As the   calculation   on the page Math Lover linked shows, the minimum surface area for a chosen volume will be attained if you make the frustum a _cylinder_ .  You need some additional constraint on the shape, such as the angle to the vertical that you want your frustum to have.  (It could still be that the _function_ you intend for your cup cannot be met by such a minimized surface area.  A conical drinking cup with minimum surface area would be very difficult to hold onto, as it would be very broad and short.)

Comment: The answer linked by Math Lover has both ends of the frustum included in the surface area, which makes a difference. With one end open, it makes sense to have the mouth wider.

Comment: The cup has an open top and closed bottom?  It is a problem in variational calculus two funtions and two variables. Suitable for a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the upside down cup be a frustum formed from a cone with base radius $b$ and height $h=cb$, where $c$ is a dimensionless constant (the cone's slope). The upper radius is $a<b$.

Then the volume is given by subtracting the volume of two cones, each a third of base area times height, $$V=\frac{\pi}{3}c(b^3-a^3).$$
The surface area is also obtained by subtracting the area of two cones, each equal to $\pi rl$, and adding the top disc (assuming the cup has a wider mouth than base): $$A=\pi (b^2-a^2)\sqrt{1+c^2}+\pi a^2$$

The question asks to minimize $A$ given $V$. Without loss of generality, we can ignore the factor of $\pi$ in the formula for $A$, and take $c(b^3-a^3)=v=3V/\pi$ as the constraint.

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers, let $$f(a,b,c):=\sqrt{1+c^2}(b^2-a^2)+a^2-\lambda c(b^3-a^3)$$ Then differentiating with respect to $a,b,c$, we get $\nabla f=0$, \begin{align}
2\sqrt{1+c^2}a-2a&=3\lambda ca^2\\
2\sqrt{1+c^2}b&=3\lambda cb^2\\
c(b^2-a^2)&=\lambda\sqrt{1+c^2}(b^3-a^3)\\
c(b^3-a^3)&=v
\end{align}

(i) Solving these (with computing help), gives, assuming $a\ne0$, $$a=\sqrt[6]{\frac{44}{63 \sqrt{7}}-\frac{16}{63}} x\approx0.464x,\quad b=\sqrt[6]{\frac{13}{126}+\frac{44}{63 \sqrt{7}}} x\approx0.846x,\quad c=\sqrt{\frac{14+8 \sqrt{7}}{9}}\approx1.977,\quad \lambda=
   \frac{2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{7}}}{3 x}$$ where $x=v^{1/3}$.
The height of the cup is $c(b-a)\approx0.755x$.

The volume is then $\frac{\pi v}{3}=V$ while the surface area is $$A=\sqrt[3]{\frac{2+\sqrt{7}}{2}} \pi  x^2\approx4.16x^2\approx4.03V^{2/3}$$

(ii) The alternative is $a=0$, for which the cup becomes an open cone. Then $$V=\frac{\pi}{3}cb^3,\qquad A=\pi b^2\sqrt{1+c^2}$$ A straightforward minimization of $A$ keeping $V$ fixed, gives $$0=\frac{dA}{db}=\frac{d}{db}\pi b^2\sqrt{1+v^2/b^6}\iff b=\left(\frac{3}{\pi\sqrt2}\right)^{1/3}V^{1/3}$$ $$A=\pi b^2\sqrt{1+c^2}=3^{7/6}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{1/3}V^{2/3}\approx4.188V^{2/3}$$

So it is option (i) that minimizes the area.

The shape looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reponse!

Comment: @ReeseZ I added a part to the answer to make it complete (considering $a=0$); it does not affect the result.